# Windows App SDK The Right Framework For Porting a Project?

Tags: windows, c++

We have our own C++ rendering engine at work. I use either UWP or Win32 exclusively for windowing and then build the entire UI and functionality using the engine. There's a new project which requires the use of the native Windows UI, hello world of pain. Which one should I choose? Do I bite the bullet and dive straight into Windows App SDK? Microsoft has so many frameworks to choose from.

Requirements are:

- No sandbox environment (that's UWP out, think it's gradually becoming an irrlevance anyway)
- Modern UI
- Access to low level Win32 APIs
- A framework which is actually going to be around for more than a few years before it gets ditched!
- No third party libs like Qt etc.

C++ is preferred, I do not want to have to mess around with any interop. Maybe if there's some minimal handoffs to the engine then C# could be OK.

Much appreciated!